# Error in Repeat Loop - if/else statement problem

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the highest Fibonacci number before 5000. this is the code I have so far:

```
n <- 5000
fib <- c()
fib[1] <- 1
fib[2] <- 1
c <- 1
i <- 3
repeat {
  fib[i] <- fib[i-1] + fib[i-2]
  i <- i+1
  c <- c+1
  if (fib[i]>=5000) {
    break
  }
h <- fib[c]
print(h)
}
```

The error I receive is:

```
Error in if (fib[i] >= 5000) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Any thoughts on how to resolve? I know my code isn't perfect, but I'm learning :)

Answer (score 1):

you raise `i` before the statement: `i-1` is what you want to compare. Further, this doesn't give you the highest number before 5000. So you have to execute the statement once again before `break`.

```r
n <- 5000
fib <- c()
fib[1] <- 1
fib[2] <- 1
c <- 1
i <- 3
repeat {
  fib[i] <- fib[i-1] + fib[i-2]
  i <- i+1
  c <- c+1
  if (fib[i-1] >= 5000) {
    h <- fib[c]
    print(h)
    break
  }
  h <- fib[c]
  print(h)
}
```